# Request digital certificate in Laravel

Tags: laravel, certificate, digital-signature

I want to offer the user the option to sign a PDF by using a digital certificate.

Administration nowadays provide you with a certificate that you can use to sign in their gob related sites and also to sign PDF documents.

I know how to sign a document by using FPDI library, but I do require the certificate file first.

I guess I can always request them to upload the certificate itself as a normal file, but that wouldn't make much sense, as they would also require to share their certificate password (if any) with me.

I would like my site to pop up something like the below to get their signature / certificate - is that possible?

[image]

Comment: I think this is a bit broad. There's probably a lot of ways to do this and none will work unless there is a level of trust from users. Your page will be handling the user certificate along with their password at some point and even if you "promise" not to keep any of their data, they need to believe that you're not lying. For example they can just upload their certificates without their password to your site and provide the password before signing which you can use at that time only without saving it anywhere.

Comment: But how can I make that screen in the OP to pop up @apokryfos ?

Comment: You can use [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) in JavaScript to open a custom page that you can make look like that